# Upgraded mysql server from 5.7 to 8.0 and lost local schema connections

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I had a few local schemas I seem to have lost / disconnected from when I uninstalled mysql server 5.7 and installed mysql server 8.0. Is there a way to get the schemas back or reconnect them or am I out of luck?

`C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data` still exists, is it safe to copy/paste this entire directory into the new data directory?